# How to stop certain point for adding pixels (int10h) for Assembly 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I have my code written on Assembly8086 and I am having problems generating pixels via loops and how can I set a certain amount of rows and columns for it to stop generating?

```
org  100h

mov ah, 0   ; set display mode function.
mov al, 13h ; mode 13h = 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
int 10h     ; set it!

setrow db '50'
setcol db '50'

mov ax, setcol
mov bx, setrow

mov cx, 10  ; column
mov dx, 20  ; row
mov al, 15  ; white
mov ah, 0ch ; put pixel
int 10h


addpixel:
inc cx
int 10h


cmp ax,cx    
JNE addpixel
ret
```

Comment: Use your favourite control flow structures?!

Comment: The code looks incomplete. According to your description it should generate several pixels, but there is no loop, also the program should return with ret.

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to add the JMP.

Comment: The pixel just generates infinitely, how do I make it stop at a certain point?

Comment: @lego: For a DOS-COM-file it is no problem for to terminate the program with only a ret instruction, if the codesegment is not changed and the stack is not corrupted, because DOS place an "int 20h" instruction at the top of the PSP and additional it push a zero word to the stack before executing the program.

Comment: @dirk there was no ret before the question was edited.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `loop` instruction.

```
 mov cx, 100 ; number of times to loop
addpixel:
 ; draw the pixel here
 ; remember not to mess up cx
loop addpixel
```

Using `int 10h` to draw a pixel is slow, really slow. It's faster and somewhat simpler to write directly to the video memory which in mode 13h is 0xa000:0000.

```
push 0xa000
pop  es

mov  di, 20*320+10    ; col=10, row=20
mov  cx, 100 ; number of pixels to draw
mov  al, 15  ; white
rep  stosb   ; write 100 white pixels
```

Answer (score 0):

Dusteh,

All your source lines with references to 'setcol' and 'setrow' are quite useless/not used in this little program.
When you do `cmp ax,cx` AX contains just the BIOS function number and the used color! So this comparaison is totally faulty.

As presented your program displays an horizontal line starting at (10,20) and going to the right. Because (most) BIOSes don't care too much about function parameters there's no telling what happens when this line reaches the right border of the screen at (319,20)!

I would be interested to learn what happened on the screen when you ran this program?

Answer (score 0):

Structure your code like this:

```
org 100h

mov ah, 0      ;set display mode function
mov al, 13h    ;mode 13h= 320x200 pixels, 256 colors.
int 10h        ;set it!
jmp short omit_variables ;jump over the variables, otherwise they'll be interpreted false.

left_border dw 0      ;The first X-Value you want to draw. Use DW instead of DB, cause cx and 

dx are 16 bit registers
upper_border dw 0     ;The uppermost row.
right_border dw 319   ;The right border.
bottom_border dw 199  ;The lowermost row.
omit_variables:
mov cx, [left_border] 
mov dx, [upper_border]
looping:

mov al, 15  ;white
mov ah, 0ch ;put pixel
int 10h

inc cx
cmp cx, [right_border]
jb looping             ;Repeat the inner loop until cx is over the maximal X value
mov cx, [left_border]
inc dx
cmp dx, [bottom_border]
jb looping             ;Repeat the outer loop until dx is over the maximal Y value

ret
```